# GCD, Euclid's Algorithm

Tags: java

I can't seem to find the solution to this error.. please dont judge me. beginner here.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GreatestCommonDivisor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int gcd;
        boolean again = false;

        do {
            System.out.print("First positive integer: ");
            num1 = inputPosInt();

        System.out.print("Second positive integer: ");          
            num2 = inputPosInt();
            //....
            gcd = gcd();
            (again) = tryAgain();
        } while (again);    {
                System.out.println("Thank you for testing this program.");
        }

    }

   public static int inputPosInt () {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
         int num;

        num = kbd.nextInt();

        if (num < 0) {
            System.out.println("Entered integer value is non-positive.");
            return 0;
        }
         return num;

    }

    public static int gcd(int num1, int num2) {


     if (num2==0) {
        return num1; 
            }
     return gcd(num2,num1%num2);
}


    public static boolean tryAgain() {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Would you like to try again? [Y/N]");
        char again;
        again = kbd.nextLine().charAt(0);
        if (again == 'y' || again == 'Y') {
            return true;
        }

        else if (again == 'n' || again == 'N') {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

This program requires 2 positive integer inputs, and solves its GCD, using the Euclid's Algorithm.

ERROR:
 gcd = gcd();
                  ^
  required: int,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Comment: you declared the function to require 2 ints, and you called it with none.

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand?

Answer (score 4):

When you are calling the `gcd` function, you need to pass in two integers as arguments. In your case those two integers will probably be the two that you read in. So, it should probably look like:

```
gcd = gcd(num1, num2);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have `gcd = gcd();` you aren't passing in the parameters it requires. Your method definition is `public static int gcd(int num1, int num2)`, which requires two ints.

An example for calling that would be `gcd = gcd(54, 24)`. In your case, you probably want `gcd = gcd(num1, num2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the method `gcd(int, int)` but not passing it any arguments in `gcd()`.

The `gcd(int, int)` method as written will require you give it two integers as input.